# A user deleted my craft Admin account, what to do?

Tags: craft3, admin, login, soft-deletes

A created user was able to delete the Admin account, now I can't log in Craft anymore with an admin account. How is it possible that a normal user can delete an Admin?

I'm in contact with this user to try and re-activate the Admin account because I think the Soft delete is at work here, so fingers crossed!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the normal user has an administrate permission, you can check at user -> permission. Even a normal user you still can give it an administrate user permission without change it into a admin user, but this permission is off by default for normal user.

Comment: The user had Administrate permissions indeed. I managed to contact the user and revert the deletion of my account. But there was a second problem, the account was also suspended (automated after deletion) The user in question could not lift this due a 403 Forbidden... This was weird. So I had to dive into the database and found the admin user there and managed to change the suspended status back.

I think this should be protected, the Admin account should never be able to be deleted in my opinion.